# What is the difference between these laptop display panels?

Tags: compatibility, lcd, laptop-repair

I currently have an LG LP154WE2 that has an approximately 10 pixel wide white stripe down the center of the screen. This shows up even when the computer first boots so I'm pretty sure the panel has to be replaced (I'm guessing it's damaged beyond repair).

I've found a replacement that is close but the model number is slightly different. It's an LG LP154W02. I can't find any differences - they are both glossy WSXGA+ 15.4" panels that should fit into my Dell Vostro 1500. Is there anything I should be worried about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These model numbers look very close to each other, the specifications (contrast ratio, backlight might differ, nothing to worry about ofc.) might have a small difference but the mounting, size and connector should be the same.

Just try it or if you don't dare to do that you should contact either LG or Dell.